# Import from different directories in python

Tags: python, import, package

This is my folder structure:

```
src/
  __init__py
  Lowlevel/
    __init__.py
    ModuleToCheck.Py
  Test/
    __init__.py
    ModuleToCheck_test.py
```

(`__init__.py` are empty files)

Now I want to import `ModuleToCheck.py` in `ModuleToCheck_test.py`

How am I able to do this without appending anything to `sys.path`?

---

Update:

`from ..Lowlevel import ModuleToCheck` leads to:

```
src$ python Test/ModuleToCheck_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test/ModuleToCheck_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..Lowlevel import ModuleToCheck
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html

Answer (score 3):

The following is from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

> Note that both explicit and implicit
>   relative imports are based on the name
>   of the current module. Since the name
>   of the main module is always
>   "`__main__`", modules intended for use
>   as the main module of a Python
>   application should always use absolute
>   imports.

You're running your module `ModuleToCheck_test.py` as the main module, hence the exception.

One solution is to create a `test.py` module in your `src` directory containing the following:

```
import Test.ModuleToCheck_test
```

You can then run that module using `python test.py`

Comment: +1, that is the only sane way in python to have entry point at top location, that way everything under src will be in pythonpath