# Python Imports From The Directory Above

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, directory

I have a directory structure for my python application where in the main folder I have a folder called handlers and in that file I have a base.py that all handlers should inherit from . I also have a folder called users that contains all the handlers relating to users.

```
\main
      \handlers
      base.py
      __init__.py
      \users
                __init__.py
                authenticated.py
                logout.py
```

My issue is I can't import the base in any file in the users folder but can import from the users folder. I know that I have to do something like bellow

```
from ..handlers import *
```

But that does not work for some reason all I am trying to do is import base.py into files in the users directory and other directorys I add at a later date.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "I can't import the base in any file in the users folder but can import from the users folder" means? Can you also clarify what "for some reason" means? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826955/import-from-different-directories-in-python Does it help?

Comment: I have a main file that I can import from the users file with ´from handlers.users import *´ but need to import base.py into the files in the users folder.

Comment: Where is the main file located? It also appears that you have not shown us the entire relevant directory structure... Maybe I do not understand your description, if that is the case, I'm sorry. Can you please post the reason this does not work? I.e. the error code or stacktrace...

Comment: the files need to be run as modules for relative imports to work. Are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for your help but i have now fixed the issue it was down to a missing dot from ..handlers import * should be from ...handlers import *

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/your/dir/goes/here')
from base import foo
```

Something like that should permit you to import stuff from any directory of your choosing.

Comment: may want to insert it at the beginning of path rather than the end, but yeah +1

Comment: This didn't work still getting a no module named error. I shouldn't really be doing this either as I am unsure if it is compatible with google app engine that it is running on.

Comment: Note, you can use relative paths (eg `'./'` and `'../'`) with this method, in addition to absolute paths (eg `'/home/username/code'`)

Answer (score 4):

To enable relative import, add `main/__init__.py` to make `main` directory into a Python package. The `main`'s parent directory should be in `sys.path`.