# Tell python to access resources above the path of the script

Tags: python

If you run a script from /tmp/myfolder/myscript/, and want to access a resource in myfolder, how do you do that in python?

I did get the file path with `__file__`, (I was told to not use it because it may not always be populated) but I can't do like in bash, where I "cd .."  to get to the previous directory, because Python does not understand that.

I would like to run the python script and no matter where the folder is, it will always go up one level and get the resource that I need.

Comment: I think you can be pretty sure `__file__` will be populated in your case. So, `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')` is your best way to get parent directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does understand `cd`: `os.chdir()`. I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you can try:

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
```

This will change your working directory to the one above the current one (just like `cd ..`).

You can also use `..` for many operations that use paths. For example, if you want to open a file that is up one directory: `open('../myfile.txt')`, etc. You may also find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030751/python-imports-from-the-directory-above) useful, depending on what your goal is.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I do have a script that run in a sub directory of my project, while an asset is in the parent folder, so to access that element, I need to go one level up. This allow me to change the cwd, so I can access the asset, Thanks!

Comment: I would still rather use `__file__` than CWD. Current working directory really does not have to be where the script is, for example if you run `python dirname/script.py`, CWD will be one level up from the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear about exactly what you are talking about, but I infer that you are talking about intra-package references. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), but the general concept is you use `from .. import module` when trying to import a module from another package.

The `..` in the statement tells the compiler to go up one level and look for a module named `module`. You can also use `for . import module`, which will import the 
module `name` from the current directory and `from ../folder import module`